# git fetch overwrote the current main with an old push to another remote, how to get my main back to how it is on github?

Tags: git, git-fetch

I wanted to get the tags that another contributor added to a github remote, so I ran `git fetch --all --tags`.  The resulting fetch looked like this:

```
$ git fetch --all --tags
Fetching origin
remote: Enumerating objects: 34, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (34/34), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Total 34 (delta 13), reused 34 (delta 13), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (34/34), 3.78 KiB | 10.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/myname/myrepo
 * [new branch]      chore/docker-setup -> origin/chore/docker-setup
 * [new branch]      fix/lib-paths      -> origin/fix/lib-paths
 * [new tag]         0.1.0              -> 0.1.0
 * [new tag]         1.0.0              -> 1.0.0
 * [new tag]         1.1.0              -> 1.1.0
 * [new tag]         1.2.0              -> 1.2.0
Fetching heroku
Fetching anotherRemote
```

My local repo now has the contents of `anotherRemote`, which I haven't pushed to in over a year, I'm guessing that's because `anotherRemote` was the final remote that was fetched? But when I tried pulling from `origin` I got:

```
$ git pull origin main
From https://github.com/myname/myrepo
 * branch            main -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

How do I get the contents of my local repo to actually match what's in `origin`?

Comment: `git fetch` does _not_ move any of the local branches of your repo so _"My local repo now has the contents of anotherRemote"_ sounds.... inaccurate... unless  with _"having"_ you only mean _"keeping a local copy of those references"_ (as remote references).

Comment: Just in case.... if you want your local branch to look like any other branch (local or remote), disregarding any changes/commits in your branch, use `git reset --hard`: `git checkout main; git reset --hard origin/main` (**warning**: destroys any changes in your working tree that are not committed... and you are potentially overwriting history).

Comment: @eftshift0 all I know is that the local files now look like they did a year ago when I pushed to `anotherRemote`, as opposed to how they look on GItHub.

Comment: ok, `git reset --hard origin/main` seems to have worked.

Comment: Ok... but _for sure_ that's not coming from `git fetch`. Git fetch does _not_ mess up with your working tree or (local) branches, nothing moves. Glad to know you are back on track.

Comment: @eftshift0 ok there is definitely something wrong here. I ran `git checkout tags/1.2.0 -b 1.2.0-database-issue`, and all the files reverted to that year-old version.  Is there maybe something about the way I fetched the tags that is causing this `anotherRepo` version to be checked out when I create a branch with a tag?

Comment: is `1.2.0` (the tag) pointing to that year-old commit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248709/discussion-between-sigil-and-eftshift0).